# Textview Width of "0dip" cutting off text inside of a TableLayout

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I'm having an issue in one of my activities with text being cut-off at the first letter.

The issue is, whenever navigating away from this activity to another (via the tabs at the top), and then going back to this activity, all of the text except the first letter in all of the textviews gets cut-off:

[image]

The funny thing is that every time I repeat this process (leaving the activity and going back), the text comes back, gets cut-off, comes back, gets cut off....repeating.

My table layout is defined as follows:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/statisticsMiddleTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/statisticsMiddleTextTitleLayout"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
```

With all rows having the following structure:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1Statistics">
    <!-- TitleRow -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statisticsTableR1CLText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/statisticsTableR1CLText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FF6600"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statisticsTableR1CRText"
            android:text="@string/statisticsTableR1CRText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFF66"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
```

I have found that setting "android:layout_width" to something other than "0dip" for the textviews solves this problem and the text doesn't get cut-off, but then I can't get an equal width between the textviews.  I'd have to rebuild the entire activity UI without a table, which I don't want to do.

The more interesting factor is that this does not happen on a real device (I only have one to test it on though) and I had never seen this bug before upgrading the android SDK tools to Revision 10.

So now I wonder, is this a bug in the SDK revision 10 tools, or should I rework the entire UI for this activity?  Has anyone else experienced this issue with using "0dip" for the "layout_width" textview attribute inside of a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget about the SDK tools and just worry about the emulator and devices. The majority of my layouts do not render correctly in the layout editor.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  These screenshots are from the emulator though, not the layout editor, if that's what you're referring to.  Otherwise, yes, I don't even use the layout editor to make UI's, I go right to the XML.  The layout editor is horrible IMHO.